# Use date_format in model or controller?

Tags: php

I have retrieving a date and time from the database in this format:

2017-11-25 21:08:48

What I had done before using MVC was:

```
$date = date_create($row['article_date']);
$article_date = date_format($date, "d F Y - h:ia");
echo $article_date;
```

I am not sure how to do this using MVC.

My model:

```
public function getPosts() {

        $this->db->query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `article`, `article_date`, `slug` FROM `news`");
        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;
    }
```

The controller:

```
public function index() {

        $posts = $this->postModel->getPosts();

        $data = [

            'posts' => $posts
        ];

        $this->view('posts/index', $data);
    }
```

Then in the view I would have:

```
<?php foreach ($data['posts'] as $post){  ?>
  // some html here
<?php echo $post->article_date; ?>
```

I can't just use date_format on the $post->article_date without first using date_create. But I just am not sure where I would use date_create i.e.: would you do that in the model or controller before passing to the view?

Comment: _"Use date_format in model or controller?"_ Neither. Data formatting belongs in the view.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, thank you for that clarification. I guess my question then changes to, how do I use date_format and date_create together because I have to use date_create on the date record before I can use date_format for formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I see that Obsidian Age answered this below..

Comment: Note also, if you're using an existing MVC framework, it probably has view helper functions for doing exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, no I am building a very simple one from scratch for learning purposes. Once I get the hang of it in its most basic form I will move onto frameworks that do all the heavy lifting for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ideally** you'd do it in neither, and instead do it in the **view**:

```
<?php foreach($data['posts'] as $post){ ?>
  // Some HTML here
<?php
    $date = date_create($post->article_date);
    $article_date = date_format($date, "d F Y - h:ia");
    echo $article_date;
  } // Remember to close the foreach!
?>
```

**However**, note that you don't need to mess around with **[`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)** at all, and can simply use **[`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** in combination with **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** instead:

```
echo date('d F Y - h:ia', strtotime($post->article_date));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes, that helped a load! Thanks so much for that :)